# Prune a dataframe based on row-wise column similarity in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, data-manipulation

I have a very large dataframe of genomic loci with genotypes scored as 0, 1, or 2. Here is a very small sample that I think gets at the issue:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4
0   0   1   0
0   0   1   0
1   1   2   1
1   1   1   1
2   2   0   1
2   2   1   2
```

Loci x1 and x2 are identical while x4 is highly similar. What I am hoping to achieve is to create a function, or use one that already exists, to assign similarity scores, row-wise, for each of my loci and then prune the dataset based on a threshold similarity that I set.

For example, if I set the threshold at 1 (100%), it would prune only x1 and x2 as they are duplicates - which I know how to do. However, if I set the threshold at 0.8, or 80% similarity, it would also prune x4 in addition to x1 and x2.

It's important that the function acts on row-wise similarity and doesn't just compare that columns have similar distributions of 0's, 1's, and 2's.

Comment: One of these might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+sequence+similarity ,  or you might try package **arules** for similarity algorithms for sequences. No own experience, though.

Comment: So insertions and deletions (where the columns are identical but off-by-one) should not count as similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this.

First, get a listing of all the unique pairings of your column names:

```r
pairs <- expand.grid(names(df), names(df))
pairs <- pairs[lower.tri(replicate(length(df), names(df))),]

pairs
#>    Var1 Var2
#> 2    x2   x1
#> 3    x3   x1
#> 4    x4   x1
#> 7    x3   x2
#> 8    x4   x2
#> 12   x4   x3
```

Now iterate through this to compare the proportion of rows that are identical in each unique pair of columns of your original data set. This gives you a similarity score between 0 to 1 for each column pair:

```r
pairs$similarity <- apply(pairs, 1, function(x) sum(df[x[1]] == df[x[2]])/nrow(df))

pairs
#>    Var1 Var2 similarity
#> 2    x2   x1  1.0000000
#> 3    x3   x1  0.1666667
#> 4    x4   x1  0.8333333
#> 7    x3   x2  0.1666667
#> 8    x4   x2  0.8333333
#> 12   x4   x3  0.1666667
```

Now remove all the rows of this listing that have a similarity score below your chosen threshold (we'll make it 0.8 here)

```r
pairs <- pairs[which(pairs$similarity > 0.8),]

pairs
#>   Var1 Var2 similarity
#> 2   x2   x1  1.0000000
#> 4   x4   x1  0.8333333
#> 8   x4   x2  0.8333333
```

Now we extract all the unique column names in `Var1` and `Var2`, since these are the columns that are similar to at least one other column:

```r
keep_cols <- as.character(sort(unique(c(pairs$Var1, pairs$Var2))))
#> [1] "x1" "x2" "x4"
```

And we subset our original data frame using this to get our desired result:

```r
df[match(keep_cols, names(df))]
#>   x1 x2 x4
#> 1  0  0  0
#> 2  0  0  0
#> 3  1  1  1
#> 4  1  1  1
#> 5  2  2  1
#> 6  2  2  2
```

Of course, you could put all this in a function to make it easier to adjust your threshold and apply iteratively:

```r
remove_dissimilar <- function(df, threshold = 0.8) {
  
  pairs <- expand.grid(names(df), names(df))
  pairs <- pairs[lower.tri(replicate(length(df), names(df))),]
  pairs$similarity <- apply(pairs, 1, function(x) {
    sum(df[x[1]] == df[x[2]])/nrow(df)})
  pairs <- pairs[which(pairs$similarity > threshold),]
  keep_cols <- as.character(sort(unique(c(pairs$Var1, pairs$Var2))))
  df[match(keep_cols, names(df))]
}
```

So now you could just do:

```r
remove_dissimilar(df, 0.8)
#>   x1 x2 x4
#> 1  0  0  0
#> 2  0  0  0
#> 3  1  1  1
#> 4  1  1  1
#> 5  2  2  1
#> 6  2  2  2

remove_dissimilar(df, 0.9)
#>   x1 x2
#> 1  0  0
#> 2  0  0
#> 3  1  1
#> 4  1  1
#> 5  2  2
#> 6  2  2
```

Comment: This is amazing Allan. Just out of curiosity. Is there a way to flip this around so I remove columns that are above the threshold instead of below it? In other words, remove_similar?

Comment: @Melderon I think you can just change the last line to `df[!names(df) %in% keep_cols]`